# How to change values to N/A in R?

Tags: r

Part of my dataset looks something like below:
[image]

How do I filter this to replace values under the heading “positive” to N/A from week ending the 19-10-20?

Thanks!

Comment: can you try df$Positive[df$`Week Ending`>='19-10-20'] <- NA , enclose Week Ending in ` sign

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your data example as text rather than as an image? Images are unsearchable and inaccessible to visually impaired people ...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your date is in format day-month-year (dmy), and that the column `Week Ending` of your dataset is not of *Date* class, you can run the code below to change all dates after 19-10-20, including it, to *NA*.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data %<>% mutate(`Week Ending` = dmy(`Week Ending`)) %>%
     mutate(Positive = if_else(`Week Ending` >= dmy("19-10-20"), NA, `Week Ending`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In the future, please try to post a  [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), which can help respondents better understand and diagnose your issues.

To answer your question, you can accomplish this using selection syntax in R.  Below is a reproducible example for your desired outcome.

```
Week_ending<-c("12-10-20","19-10-20", "26-10-20")
Positive<-c(5.6,7.9,2.4)
Negative<-c(3.5,4.9,1.7)

df<-data.frame(Week_ending=format(as.Date(Week_ending, format="%d-%m-%y"),"%d-%m-%y"), Positive=Positive, Negative=Negative)
df$Positive[df$Week_ending=="19-10-20"]<-NA # This is the line that accomplishes what you are after
df
```

In the line that I have flagged in the code block above, I use the dollar sign `$` and square brace `[]` operators.

The dollar sign means select a column, and the square braces can be interpreted as a more generic approach to selection. Breaking down the syntax

`df$Positive` means "select the **Positive** column from the **df** dataframe"

`[df$Week_ending=="19-10-20"]`means "where the value of the **Week_ending** column in the **df** dataframe is equal to *19-10-20*

`<-NA` simply means assign these values *NA*

In plain English the whole line means "Make the value of **Positive** NA for any rows corresponding to the **Week_ending** *19-10-20* "